# PostgreSQL merging identical tables from separate databases into single database

Tags: postgresql

I've started working on a project where the application data is split across multiple databases that all have the same schema (basically there's a database per "organisation").

After some discussion it's been decided that this isn't the most efficient way for us to store data and would like to merge all of these separate databases into one single database.

I was wondering what would be the best approach. I'm currently thinking about doing something like the following:

1. Dump the schema from one of the databases and restore it to the new primary database:

   `pg_dump [OLD_DATABASE] --schema-only > dbschema.sql`

   `psql -d [NEW_DATABASE -f dbschema.sql`
2. Dump the data from all of the old databases disabling triggers, and insert format:

   `pg_dump [OLD_DATABASES] --disable-triggers --data-only --inserts > old_db_data.sql`
3. Restore all of the dumped data from database files:

   `psql [NEW_DATABASE] < old_db_data.sql`

Is this the right way to do this kind of merge or am I completely off the mark? Additionally will this handle foreign key dependencies correctly?

Comment: You don't need inserts, the usual `COPY` will be good enough (or even better).  Furthermore, if there is a set of common data (in lookup tables, like types of something), you might need a different approach  for those.  Before loading the data, you will disable/remove FKs in any case, so that should be no issue, if there are no conflicts between the existing DBs (I mean, for example, that type A has a different ID in two DBs).

Comment: @dezso, ok thanks for the tip. I'll have a look into what you said and see how I go.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is easily improved, however you're mostly there.

When you run this

```bash
pg_dump [OLD_DATABASE] --schema-only > dbschema.sql
```

Instead do

```bash
pg_dump [OLD_DATABASE] --schema-only --section pre-data > pre.sql
```

Then load your dumped data, produced by this (from all the servers)

```bash
pg_dump [OLD_DATABASES] --disable-triggers --data-only --inserts > old_db_data.sql
```

But, then you need to add the add the constraints.. So go back to your original database and run

```bash
pg_dump [OLD_DATABASE] --schema-only --section post-data > post.sql
```

And, then load post.sql. This will add the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql 9.3 or superior I strongly suggest you to use extension [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).

With that you can create a new empty database as you suggested in your post (#1) and create a different schema per "organisation" in which you'll have foreign tables corresponding to that "organisation" database.

It'll be like having all your databases in one.
Using simple `INSERT INTO main.table SELECT * FROM org1.table` you can migrate data from one database to another.
You can check for data integrity using joins between similar tables in different schemas.
And if you like you can go on with this setup without any merging until you decide is the best time to do so.

If you choose to use this extension you should read the extensive documentation on the subject or ask more question in SO to get your initial setup running.

Comment: That would be super slow.